# friend function is not a friend of all template instances?

Tags: c++, friend-function, access-specifier, template-classes

In the following example I try to access the private member function `subscribe()` from a templated class type from within its friend function. However it appears that the friend function is only befriended in one instantiation of the class and not the other, hence yielding a "private within this context"-error. Check out the  following:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+my_class%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename...+Ts%3E%0A++++friend+auto+observe(my_class%3CTs%3E...+args)+%7B%0A++++++++(%5B%26%5D%7B+args.subscribe()%3B+%7D(),+...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+subscribe()+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22subscribed!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++my_class%3Cint%3E+a%7B%7D%3B%0A++++my_class%3Cbool%3E+b%7B%7D%3B%0A++++observe(a,b)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class my_class
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    friend auto observe(my_class<Ts>... args) {
        ([&]{ args.subscribe(); }(), ...);
    }

    void subscribe() {
        printf("subscribed!\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_class<int> a{};
    my_class<bool> b{};
    observe(a,b);
}
```

**Error**:

```
<source>:19:20:   required from here
<source>:7:17: error: redefinition of 'template<class ... Ts> auto observe(my_class<Ts>...)'
    7 |     friend auto observe(my_class<Ts>... args) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~
<source>:7:17: note: 'template<class ... Ts> auto observe(my_class<Ts>...)' previously declared here
<source>: In instantiation of 'auto observe(my_class<Ts>...) [with Ts = {int, bool}; T = int]':
<source>:20:12:   required from here
<source>:8:29: error: 'void my_class<T>::subscribe() [with T = bool]' is private within this context
    8 |         ([&]{ args.subscribe(); }(), ...);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:11:10: note: declared private here
   11 |     void subscribe() {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

Is this actually correct by the compiler?

Comment: `class<T1s...>` and `class<T2s...>` are distinct classes unless `T1s...` is the same as `T2s...`. This means, friends are distinct, too.

Comment: It seems you just have two separate errors here: ambiguous static function - https://godbolt.org/z/EWcsff7vW and not accessible private members from different template specialization - https://godbolt.org/z/oPbhbPnMf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

`my_class<int>` and `my_class<bool>` are separate classes, and everything inside them will get defined separately for each instantiation of the template.  Normally this is fine, because the stuff inside the classes is class members, so i.e. `my_class<int>::subscribe` and `my_class<bool>::subscribe` are different functions.

But `observe` is not a class member, so the fact that it gets defined by both `my_class<int>` and `my_class<bool>` is a violation of the One Definition Rule.

What you need to do is move the definition of `observe` outside of `my_class` so that it only gets defined once:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class my_class
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    friend auto observe(my_class<Ts>... args);

    void subscribe() {
        printf("subscribed!\n");
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
auto observe(my_class<Ts>... args) {
    ([&]{ args.subscribe(); }(), ...);
}

int main()
{
    my_class<int> a{};
    my_class<bool> b{};
    observe(a,b);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a45f2fbda28fb49)

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't get is how the friend function is defined multiple times? It is not template parameter dependent and I thought it would always be put into surrounding scope context, so both classes would actually reference the same friend function?